# Download files from Unix server using WinSCP with get command

Tags: windows, sftp, winscp

I have program in Unix that generates files 8 files at 8:30 pm everyday.

I need to download the files into my Windows machine after the files are generated using WinSCP.

I can drag and drop those but its time consuming, I need to automate this process.

I cannot use .Net assembly to download those.

I have tried to use the `get` command, but its throwing error: Not an SCCS file.

Let me know how can I solve this.

--Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To automate a task using WinSCP, use its [scripting interface](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting) from a batch file (e.g. `download.bat`).

*I assume you want to use SFTP, as you are connecting to a *nix server.*

The simplest download batch file is like:

```
winscp.com /log=c:\path\to\log\winscp.log /command ^
    "open sftp://username:password@example.com/ -hostkey=""xxx""" ^
    "get /path/to/file.ext c:\path\to\download\to\" ^
    "exit"
```

Replace the `username`, `password` and `example.com` with the actual connection details. Get the value of `-hostkey` switch [from your GUI session](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_hostkey). Use real paths.

Though it's easier to have [WinSCP generate the batch file for you](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#generating).

For details see a [guide to automating file transfers from SFTP server using WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation).

---

Once you have the batch file working, schedule the the batch file execution using Windows scheduler.

See a [guide to scheduling file transfers from SFTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_schedule).